# Swap array values with php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
array(
    0 => 'contact',
    1 => 'home',
    2 => 'projects'
);
```

and I need to swap the 'contact' with 'home', so the array would be like:

```
array(
    0 => 'home',
    1 => 'contact',
    2 => 'projects'
);
```

how can I do this with PHP? :)

Comment: Can't you just use a temp variable to make the swap?

Comment: If you need to sort the array, you need to define a clear sorting criteria.

Comment: Maybe a better question: Why is it out of order in the first place?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try this:

```
$a = array(
    0 => 'contact',
    1 => 'home',
    2 => 'projects'
);
$temp = $a[0];
$a[0] = $a[1];
$a[1] = $temp;
```

Answer (score 53):

I wrote simple function `array_swap`: swap two elements between positions `swap_a` & `swap_b`.

```
function array_swap(&$array,$swap_a,$swap_b){
   list($array[$swap_a],$array[$swap_b]) = array($array[$swap_b],$array[$swap_a]);
}
```

For OP question (for example):

```
$items = array(
  0 => 'contact',
  1 => 'home',
  2 => 'projects'
);

array_swap($items,0,1);
var_dump($items);
// OUTPUT

array(3) {
   [0]=> string(4) "home"
   [1]=> string(7) "contact"
   [2]=> string(8) "projects"
 }
```

**Update**
Since PHP 7.1 it's possible to do it like:

```
$items = [
  0 => 'contact',
  1 => 'home',
  2 => 'projects'
];

[$items[0], $items[1]] = [$items[1], $items[0]];

var_dump($items);
// OUTPUT

array(3) {
   [0]=> string(4) "home"
   [1]=> string(7) "contact"
   [2]=> string(8) "projects"
 }
```

It's possible through [Symmetric array destructuring](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php).

Comment: The 2nd method can also be done with `list()`: `list($items[0], $items[1]) = [$items[1], $items[0]];` (supported in PHP versions prior to 7.1)

Answer (score 8):

In PHP 7.1+ syntax, you can use this

```
[$Array[$a], $Array[$b]] = [$Array[$b], $Array[$a]];
```

Comment: This did not work and returned `syntax error, unexpected '='`
What would this fall under in PHP 7?

Comment: (don't forget the semicolon) 7.1, not just version 7 or any sub versions @Jordan

Comment: @Jordan http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.symmetric-array-destructuring

Comment: It wasn't me. 

Answer (score 7):

Just use a temp variable to hold one value as you swap the other. Then restore the first with the temp variable. For numbers there are [other methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swap_%28computer_science%29) that don't require the use of temp variables but here it's the best (only?) way.

```
$a = array(
    0 => 'contact',
    1 => 'home',
    2 => 'projects'
);

print_r($a);
Array ( [0] => contact [1] => home [2] => projects )

$tmp = $a[0];
$a[0] = $a[1];
$a[1] = $tmp;

print_r($a);
Array ( [0] => home [1] => contact [2] => projects )
```

Comment: Why _PriestVallon_'s answers has more voteups and is accepted one? Yours come five minutes before his and is actually exactly the same (which makes me fear, that he duped your answer)?

Answer (score 4):

New answer: (as others have expressed)

I was not aware of Symmetric Array Destructuring at the time of posting, but that is a functionless, one-liner swapping technique -- I'd use that all day long.

A [relevant blog post/tutorial](https://stitcher.io/blog/array-destructuring-with-list-in-php).  An [example implemention for bubble sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60012548/2943403).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/nDUpG))

```
$a = ['contact', 'home', 'projects'];

[$a[0], $a[1]] = [$a[1], $a[0]];

var_export($a);
```

---

Old answer:

If you want to avoid using temporary data storage, or love a one-liner use `array_replace()`.

`array_replace()` will make adjustments in accordance with the indices:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a3e478946c05496d9541a97e6c1f475e5c15d2a1))

```
$a = array(
    0 => 'contact',
    1 => 'home',
    2 => 'projects'
);

var_export(array_replace($a,[$a[1],$a[0]]));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'home',
  1 => 'contact',
  2 => 'projects',
)
```

Comment: Beside the performance, this only works in the very special case swapping elements with keys 0 and 1. It may be a tempting one-liner for users who want a new array instead of an inplace swap though. In this case, a more explicit form such as `array_replace($a, [I => $a[J], J => $a[I]])` would be more readable and less error-prone in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention.  This answer was not reflecting my current advice, so I have edited.  Cheers.

Comment: Since v7.4 you can do `[$a[1], $a[0]] = $a;` aswell :)

Comment: That is suitable for changing the first two elements in this case, but don't try the same thing with the 2nd and 3rd elements.  https://3v4l.org/hRbnI @SirPilan

Comment: In this case you'd prepend a `,` - [example](https://3v4l.org/SENJC). This is suitable for small arrays only, so i get your point.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a temp variable to hold it. So:

```
$temp = $array[0];
$array[0] = $array[1];
$array[1] = $temp;
```

That way you don't lose the value of one of them.

Answer (score 3):

I tested the 4 ways proposed to compare the performance:

```
$array=range(0,9999); //First 10000 natural numbers
$time=-microtime(true); //Start time
for($i=0;$i<1000000;++$i){ //1 Millon swaps
    $a=array_rand($array); //Random position: ~60ms
    $b=array_rand($array); //Random position: ~60ms
    //Using a temp variable: ~70ms
    $temp=$array[$a];$array[$a]=$array[$b];$array[$b]=$temp;
    //Using list language construct: ~ 140ms
    list($array[$a],$array[$b])=array($array[$b],$array[$a]);
    //Using PHP 7.1+ syntax: ~ 140ms
    [$array[$a],$array[$b]]=[$array[$b],$array[$a]];
    //Using array_replace function: ~ 28000ms
    array_replace($array,[$array[$a],$array[$b]]);
}
$time+=microtime(true); //Elapsed time
echo "Time: ",sprintf('%f', $time)," seconds";
```

Although it is probably not the most comfortable way, using a temporary variable seems to be **2x** faster than the next 2 methods, and **400x** faster than using the *array_replace* function.

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = array(
    0 => 'home',
    1 => 'contact',
    2 => 'projects'
);

$t = $array[0];
$array[0] = $array[1];
$array[1] = $t;
```

would be a simple enough approach…

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
array_splice($x, 1, 2, array_reverse(array_slice($x, 1, 2)));
var_dump($x);
```

array_splice can replace a reversed array_slice

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
$a = array(
    0 => 'contact',
    1 => 'home',
    2 => 'projects'
);
```

`list($a[0], $a[1]) = [$a[1], $a[0]];`

I have made function for it

```
function swap(&$a, &$b){
    list($a, $b) = [$b, $a];
}
```

Usage:

`swap($a[0], $a[1]);`