# how to shift first element of array to the last?

Tags: php, arrays

We have to show the first element of the array to the last Check below code

```
public function getFilters(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer)
{
    if (!count($this->filters)) {
        $this->filters = [
            $this->objectManager->create(
                $this->filterTypes[self::CATEGORY_FILTER], 
                ['layer' => $layer]
            ),
        ];
        foreach ($this->filterableAttributes->getList() as $attribute) {
            $this->filters[] = $this->createAttributeFilter($attribute, $layer);
        }
    }
    return $this->filters;
}
```

The result of $this->filters will look like

```
$this->filters[0] = Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Category
$this->filters[1] = Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute
$this->filters[2] = Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute
$this->filters[3] = Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute
$this->filters[4] = Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute
```

How to move it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [array_shift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) for this:

```
$data = array_shift($this->filters);
$this->filters[]=  $data;
```

Sample output:- https://3v4l.org/WULpM

Answer (score 0):

It depends, do you want to swap the first and last element, or would you want to remove the element from the end of the array and prepend it to the beginning (effectively having moved  all elements on further).
For the former, you could use (as mentioned at [Swap array values with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298251/swap-array-values-with-php))

```
$temp = $filters[0];
$a[0] = $filters[count($filters) - 1];
$a[1] = $temp;
```

For the latter you could use:

```
$first_element = array_unshift($filters)
array_push($first_element)
```