# How to swap two values in array with indexes?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

For example i have an array like this `$array = ('a' => 2, 'b' => 1, 'c' => 4);` and i need to swap `a` with `c` to get this `$array = ('c' => 4, 'b' => 1, 'a' => 2);`. Wht is the best way for doing this without creating new array? I know that it is possible with XOR, but i also need to save indexes.

Comment: What kind of logic does the swap follow?

Comment: @kingkero keys represents some names in a particular order.

Comment: @Pranavc as i said before - i need to save key => value structure.

Comment: And you can't use [`uksort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.uksort.php) for this? Sorry, but we'll need more information to give you an appropriate answer

Comment: @Pranavc OP doesn't want to change values only but keep the associative indices!

Comment: I would think `array_splice` is your friend here.

Comment: @kingkero i need to swap just two values, not all array. I just know that the default order is `a,b,c` and i need to change to `c,b,a` saving it's values.

Comment: perhaps `list` may help you?.. like: `list ($array['a'],$array['c']) = array ($array['c'],$array['a']);`

Comment: @Kirix then deceze's comment seems to be quite an eligable solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switch two items in associative array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448345/switch-two-items-in-associative-array)

Comment: @briosheje nope, it just swaps values. And i need to swap keys with valuest

Answer (score 1):

`array_splice` would be perfect, but unfortunately it doesn't preserve the keys in the inserted arrays. So you'll have to resort to a little more manual slicing and dicing:

```
function swapOffsets(array $array, $offset1, $offset2) {
    list($offset1, $offset2) = array(min($offset1, $offset2), max($offset1, $offset2));

    return array_merge(
        array_slice($array, 0, $offset1, true),
        array_slice($array, $offset2, 1, true),
        array_slice($array, $offset1 + 1, $offset2 - $offset1 - 1, true),
        array_slice($array, $offset1, 1, true),
        array_slice($array, $offset2 + 1, null, true)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to purely swap the first and the last positions, here's one way to do it:

```
$first = array(key($array) => current($array)); // Get the first key/value pair
array_shift($array); // Remove it from your array

end($array);
$last = array(key($array) => current($array)); // Get the last key/value pair
array_pop($array); // Remove it from the array

$array = array_merge($last, $array, $first); // Put it back together
```

Gives you:

```
Array
(
    [c] => 4
    [b] => 1
    [a] => 2
)
```

Working example: http://3v4l.org/r87qD

**Update:** And just for fun, you can squeeze that down quite a bit:

```
$first = array(key($array) => current($array));
$last = array_flip(array(end($array) => key($array)));
$array = array_merge($last, array_slice($array,1,count($array) - 2), $first);
```

Working example: http://3v4l.org/v6R7T

**Update 2:**

Oh heck yeah, we can *totally* do this in one line of code now:

```
$array = array_merge(array_flip(array(end($array) => key($array))), array_slice($array,1,count($array) - 2), array_flip(array(reset($array) => key($array))));
```

Working example: http://3v4l.org/QJB5T

That was fun, thanks for the challenge. =)

Comment: this functions sorts all array, but i need only those values

Comment: @jszobody That seems like way too much work.  See my example.

Comment: I see.  I should've read all the comments.  It didn't occur to me that the order of the keys was important.  My apologies.

Comment: @Crashspeeder No biggie. It is an odd question, I'm curious why the OP really even needs to do this. But fun nonetheless.

Comment: note, id didmt. I didn't say that i need to swap first/last, i said i need to swap one with other.