# Swap multidimensional array keys with php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, swap

I have two keys and want to swap them in a multidimensional array.

I Have referred these [Swap array values with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298251/swap-array-values-with-php), [How to swap two values in array with indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426566/how-to-swap-two-values-in-array-with-indexes)
 references but didn't get any help.

I have this array,

```
[
    'box-a' => 'email',
    'box-b' => 'job',
    'box-c' => 'company',
    'box-d' => 'candidate',
    'box-e' => 'calender',
    'box-f' => 'smartlist',
    'box-g' => 'analytics',
]
```

And I want to swap two array keys, `box-b` and `box-e` but the array values should remain as it is.

I have tried this,

```
list($array[$swap_a], $array[$swap_b]) = array($array[$swap_b], $array[$swap_a]);
```

But didn't get success. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use temp array, like this:

```
$a = [
'box-a' => 'email',
'box-b' => 'job',
'box-c' => 'company',
'box-d' => 'candidate',
'box-e' => 'calender',
'box-f' => 'smartlist',
'box-g' => 'analytics',
];

$temp = $a['box-e'];
$a['box-e'] = $a['box-b'];
$a['box-b'] = $temp;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_replace()` in a one-liner, and avoid using temporary data storage.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4676eb06834e73045e70b44c98ff191adf5fac6c))

```
$a = [
'box-a' => 'email',
'box-b' => 'job',
'box-c' => 'company',
'box-d' => 'candidate',
'box-e' => 'calender',
'box-f' => 'smartlist',
'box-g' => 'analytics'
];

var_export(array_replace($a,['box-b'=>$a['box-e'],'box-e'=>$a['box-b']]));
```

Output:

```
array (
  'box-a' => 'email',
  'box-b' => 'calender',
  'box-c' => 'company',
  'box-d' => 'candidate',
  'box-e' => 'job',
  'box-f' => 'smartlist',
  'box-g' => 'analytics',
)
```