# Reposition element to the start of its relative sequence/group in a flat, indexed array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, array-splice

Say I have an array such as:

```
[
    ['action' => 'Created', 'timestamp' => '2023-10-30 20:51:57.284602'],
    ['action' => 'Updated', 'timestamp' => '2023-10-30 20:51:57.284603'],
    ['action' => 'Started', 'timestamp' => '2023-10-30 20:51:57.284604'],
    ['action' => 'Bid placed', 'timestamp' => '2023-10-30 20:51:57.284605'],
    ['action' => 'Max bid placed', 'timestamp' => '2023-10-30 20:51:57.284606'],
    ['action' => 'Bid placed', 'timestamp' => '2023-10-30 20:51:57.284607'],
    ['action' => 'Max bid placed', 'timestamp' => '2023-10-30 20:51:57.284608'],
    // and so on...
    ['action' => 'Ended', 'timestamp' => '2023-10-30 20:51:57.284609'],
],
```

I need to swap the order of any "bid placed" items that are together with "max bid placed" items. It is possible that there might not be any "max bid placed" items. There could also be many of these entries in the array.

e.g.

```
[
    ['action' => 'Created', 'timestamp' => '2023-10-30 20:51:57.284602'],
    ['action' => 'Updated', 'timestamp' => '2023-10-30 20:51:57.284603'],
    ['action' => 'Started', 'timestamp' => '2023-10-30 20:51:57.284604'],
    ['action' => 'Max bid placed', 'timestamp' => '2023-10-30 20:51:57.284606'],
    ['action' => 'Bid placed', 'timestamp' => '2023-10-30 20:51:57.284605'],
    ['action' => 'Max bid placed', 'timestamp' => '2023-10-30 20:51:57.284608'],
    ['action' => 'Bid placed', 'timestamp' => '2023-10-30 20:51:57.284607'],
    // and so on...
    ['action' => 'Ended', 'timestamp' => '2023-10-30 20:51:57.284609'],
],
```

I've tried a few things already but always seem to end up the following order:

```
[
    ['action' => 'Created'],
    ['action' => 'Updated'],
    ['action' => 'Started'],
    ['action' => 'Max bid placed'],
    ['action' => 'Max bid placed'],
    ['action' => 'Bid placed'],
    ['action' => 'Bid placed'],
    // and so on...
    ['action' => 'Ended'],
],
```

Is this actually possible?

Comment: Please show what you tried. We'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you.

Comment: It shouldn't be much harder than `$temp = $array[$i]; $array[$i] = $array[$i+1]; $array[$i+1] = $temp;`

Comment: In modern PHP, there is no need for a `$temp` variable [when you use square brace destructuring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46791856/2943403).

Comment: Might you ever have multiple, consecutive `Bid placed` rows? Meaning, does the solution need to potentially move 3 or more rows in a given collection of rows?

Comment: In the input array, are the Bid placed rows always first in a given group?  Is there always a Max bid placed to denote the end of a sequence of Bid placed rows?  I think we need to see another set of data or two to understand the variability of your input.  I predict that this question will receive answers that behave fundamentally differently and we won't be able to accurately separate the correct from the incorrect answers.

Comment: @mickmackusa There could potentially be 3 consecutive `Bid placed` rows, yes. There is not always a `Max bid placed` to denote the end of a sequence of `Bid placed` rows. If I could just get it so that any `Bid placed` which are followed by `Max bid placed` are reversed, that would be great.

Comment: Looks like very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/2448345/5468463

Comment: @Chris can you confirm if this technique works in 100% of your scenarios? https://3v4l.org/FSuB8  If not, please [edit] your question to clarify what isn't right.  I still think we need to see a [mcve] that demonstrates fringe cases that may be troublesome.

Comment: @mickmackusa That looks pretty great, thanks. The only thing I can see is index 8 max bid would always be followed by a bid placed.

Comment: Related: [Move an array element to a new index in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12624153/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you iterate, cache the starting point of a given group.

If a started group encounters a non-group entry before encountering a `Max bid placed` row, then abort the group.

When a group is started and suitably concluded with a `Max bid placed` row, then remove the `Max bid placed` row and re-inject it before the first row in the group.  The array will be automatically re-indexed by the `array_splice()` function call.  The subsequent row indexes will be unaffected by each manipulation because there will be no increase/decrease of the array size prior to the manipulation.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WvlIp))

```
$start = null;
foreach ($array as $i => $row) {
    if ($row['action'] === 'Bid placed') {
        $start ??= $i;  // only store the first $i in the group
        continue;
    }
    if ($start !== null && $row['action'] === 'Max bid placed') {
        array_splice($array, $start, 0, array_splice($array, $i, 1)); // prune and reinsert row
    }
    $start = null;
}
var_export($array);
```

---

<sub>I initially considered, but abandoned the following because it required too much sorting and memory for the relatively simple procedure of conditionally moving single rows in an array.</sub>

```
//                          DON'T USE THIS CODE, IT IS NOT CORRECT.
$grouper = [];
$actions = [];
$timestamps = [];
$i = 0;
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $grouper[] = $i;
    $actions[] = $row['action'];
    $timestamps[] = $row['timestamp'];
    $i += $row['action'] !== 'Bid placed';
}
array_multisort($grouper, $actions, SORT_DESC, $timestamps, $array);
var_export($array);
```